# Monitor a stream with a Supervisor in Elixir

Tags: twitter, elixir

I use the ExTwitter-library to poll data using a stream like this:

```
stream = ExTwitter.stream_sample(receive_messages: true)
for message <- stream do
  case message do
    tweet = %ExTwitter.Model.Tweet{} ->
      IO.puts "tweet = #{tweet.text}"

    deleted_tweet = %ExTwitter.Model.DeletedTweet{} ->
      IO.puts "deleted tweet = #{deleted_tweet.status[:id]}"

    limit = %ExTwitter.Model.Limit{} ->
      IO.puts "limit = #{limit.track}"

    stall_warning = %ExTwitter.Model.StallWarning{} ->
      IO.puts "stall warning = #{stall_warning.code}"

    _ ->
      IO.inspect message
  end
end
```

and it's working great but now I want to monitor the stream with a Supervisor. What is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to put this code in a function in a new module, add a `start_link` function that simply invokes this function through `spawn_link`, and add that module as a `worker` to your `Supervisor`. Here's a simple example:

```
defmodule M do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(M.Streamer, []),
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: M.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end

defmodule M.Streamer do
  def start_link do
    {:ok, spawn_link(__MODULE__, :main, [])}
  end

  def main do
    IO.inspect(self)
    for i <- Stream.cycle([1, 2, 3]) do
      IO.puts i
      :timer.sleep(1000)
    end
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
#PID<0.85.0>
iex(1)> 1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
Process.exit3pid(0, 85, 0), :kill)

#PID<0.88.0>
1
true
iex(2)> 2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
Process.exit(pid(0, 88, 0), :kill)
#PID<0.90.0>
true
1
iex(3)> 2
3
1
2
3
```

This might be a little hard to follow as the output was happening while I was typing, but all the PID values were printed whenever `Streamer` started, the `Process.exit` lines are the code entered by me, and `true` is the return value of those calls. As you can see, whenever I killed the `M.Streamer` process, it was restarted by the Supervisor.